# does Hydrogen and nickel reduce c=c

Tags: carbonyl-compounds, organic-reduction

In my course, I've come across H2 and Ni catalyst as a reducing agent for alkenes and LiAlH4/NaBH4 as a reducing agent for carbonyl groups. I know LiAlH4/NaBH4 can't reduce c=c as it is nucleophilic but can H2 and Ni reduce the carbonyl group? I've found uncertain and conflicting answers over the internet. My text book says it is possible and even gives the conditions for the reaction but past examination papers say otherwise.

**question(compound Q):**
  [image]

**answer:**
[image]

Comment: IF Ni/H2 reduced  -CO- group, it would not be used for fat hydrogenation for food purposes, as fats would not be fats any more.

Comment: you do have a point but Is there any specific reason why?Im uncertain about what I'm supposed to write on the paper as the CIE examination board has implied that it does in fact reduce the c=c bond in another place.